# How can I automatically collapse the search box in the Windows taskbar when there are a lot of applications running?

Tags: windows-10, taskbar, windows-search, multitasking

I like the large search box in the taskbar. I often use it to launch applications, and it provides a much larger touchscreen target for tapping on it.

However, there are some situations in which I'm running a lot of applications, and the search box just takes up space, leaving a really tiny space for all of those applications:

[image: Search box is expanded, so all the application icons are scrunched and harder to tap]

There is an option to collapse the search box into a button, which makes much more space for applications, but then I have to let go of the advantages above. It's also completely manual, so I have to change the setting every single time. Here's how it looks like:

[image: Search box is collapsed, leaving much more room for app icons]

Is there a way I can automatically collapse the search box into a button when there are a lot of applications running such that the buttons will be pushed together, and show it when there are few enough applications that they have enough space to not be pushed together?